# Data-binding with child's child element in Polymer

Tags: data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0, skygear

I am using Skygear as a BaaS.
I created a polymer element `skygear-app` (just like `polymerfire` do) to init the skygear instance.

```
  <skygear-app name="skygear" app={{skygear}} end-
  point="https://xyz.skygeario.com/" api-key="SECRET"></skygear-app>
```

I could also successfully do the login by

```
  passwordSignIn: function(){
    skygear.loginWithEmail(this.email, this.password).then(
      function(){
        console.log('login ok');
        console.log(skygear.currentUser.id);
        this.currentUser = skygear.currentUser;
      }
    );
```

I could get the [userId](https://docs.skygear.io/guides/auth/basics/js/userId) by `console.log(skygear.currentUser.id);`, however,
I couldn't get the userId using data-binding `{{skygear.currentUser.id}}`.

```
  <h4>Access Token: [[skygear.accessToken]]</h4> <!-- working -->
  <h4>User Id: [[skygear.currentUser.id]]</h4> <!-- not working -->
```

Level 1 attribute like `{{skygear.endpoint}}` works;
but Level 2 attribute like `{{skygear.currentUser.id}}` don't.

Is data-binding limited to 1 level only? And any idea to solve?

Answer (score 1):

According to the polymer1.0 doc, level 2 attribute is `Unobservable changes`, refs: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-system#unobservable-changes

We can use `onUserChanged` provided by skygear container to notify polymer app.

Here is the minimal working Polymer skygear-app

```
  Polymer({
    is: 'skygear-app',
      apiKey: {
        type: String
      },
      endPoint: {
        type: String
      },
      app: {
        type: Object,
        notify: true,
        computed: '__computeApp(name, apiKey, endPoint)'
      }
    },
    __computeApp: function(name, apiKey, endPoint) {
      if (apiKey && endPoint) {
        skygear.onUserChanged(() => {
          this.notifyPath('app.currentUser.id');
        });
        skygear.config({
          apiKey: apiKey,
          endPoint: endPoint
        }).then(() => {
          this.notifyPath('app.currentUser.id');
        });
        return skygear
      } else {
        return null;
      }

      return skygear
    }
  });
```

Comment: the `this` in anonymous function inside `.then()` is not the right `this`. XD

Comment: We don't have to notify after the config. They should be independent.

Comment: I think there should be 2 notifyPath.

First is for onUserChanged(), which update the value when user login, logout, or change email.

Second is on the config()/init(), which obtain the current signed-in user.
(while the scope of `this` is not the expected one in your code)